# How do I get my search results to display multiple returns across more than I row?

Tags: php, mysqli

The search I have set up returns the results I want, but I can't get them to display across multiple rows when the search result returns more than I answer.  I tried using a simple break to start a new row after each return but it didn't work.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "oldga740_SeniorProject";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


// If there is a search variable try to search database
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Client LIKE '%$searchq%'";

        if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($conn);
}






?>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<form action="Index.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...." />
  <input type="submit" value=">>" />
</form>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hint: Have a look at your HTML source, they're in there alright. `\n` is mostly used when you want to write to a file with new lines.

Comment: btw, in this day and age, use a prepared statement if you want to keep your database intact ;-)

Comment: Thanks Fred.  It was staring me in the face the entire time.  I thought I had this set up to protect my database.  Can you give me  reference to look at for prepared statements?  I'm a student and I'm learning a lot of this as I go through my text books and search engines.

Comment: You're welcome Tony. Here are a few, mysqli and PDO, being the manuals http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thanks again Fred!  I try figuring things out before I ask a question here, but after a few hours the code tends to start running together.

Comment: You're welcome Tony and I know the feeling, *cheers*

Comment: Fred, quick question.  PHP while loop doesn't support an else statement.  How can I add an else statement to show no results if the search turns up empty.  Can I nest it inside the if statement that preceeds the while statement?

Comment: you can do `while/if/else`

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll look up the syntax/structure.

Comment: btw, a `while/if/else` is useful if you want to compare to a row inside a `while` loop. I.e.: `while(condition){ if($row['col'] == "x"){...} else {...} }` type of thing.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind for something down the road.  Right now I just want a message that says no records found if the while loop doesn't return a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <br> instead of simple line feed.

```
printf ("%s (%s)<br/>", $row[0], $row[1]);
```

Comment: And why you output it outside of html markup? That's wrong.

Comment: @AntonTodua you're right, but I was more concerned with getting it to run properly than where the output was initially placed.  I plan on placing it within the html markup.

Comment: Thanks for the help @AntonTodua!!  That did the trick.  I didn't have the <br> tag formatted properly.